# Parsing xml data in BGG xml api with R

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

This question is a second part to this question: [How to parse xml lists and tables in R for BGG API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841568/how-to-parse-xml-lists-and-tables-in-r-for-bgg-api).

I want to produce a data frame for this table:

```
<marketplacelistings>
  <listing>
    <listdate>Thu, 19 Jan 2006 22:08:15 +0000</listdate>
    <price currency="EUR">90.00</price>
    <condition>likenew</condition>
    <notes>Siedler von Catan / Settlers of Catan-Set (Basisspiel/basic game + Erweiterungen Die Seefahrer/ Städte und Ritter/ 5-6 Spieler / extensions The Seafarers/ Cities and Knights/ 5-6 players); 3 x gespielt (Neuwertig; lediglich alle Bestandteile in EINER der Originalboxen verstaut) / 3 times played (like new; only all items in ONE original box stored); Abgabe nur komplett / selling only all together; KEIN Festpreis (nur um überhaupt etwas einzugeben) – erwarte Angebot! / no fixed price (just to complete the entries)– make an offer; Versand weltweit zu Lasten Käufer / shipping worldwide, paid by buyer</notes>
    <link href="https://boardgamegeek.com/market/product/40605" title="marketlisting"/>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <listdate>Mon, 29 Sep 2008 15:25:32 +0000</listdate>
    <price currency="USD">34.95</price>
    <condition>new</condition>
    <notes>Brand New Sealed Board Game. Released from MayFair Games. Price is in USD. If you wish to pay in CAD...then we will convert at market rate. Shipping is $10.95 USD. We also carry the 5-6 Player Expansion that goes with this for $24.95 USD. We have sold thousands of board games across Canada. Please feel free to buy with confidence.</notes>
    <link href="https://boardgamegeek.com/market/product/116347" title="marketlisting"/>
  </listing>
```

Here is where i don't know what to do.  There's about 100 listings for this game, and I want to make a data frame from them.  Where do I start?  The code below doesn't work, as it gives
a NULL result.

```
listings_df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(
  getNodeSet(xmltop, '//marketplacelistings'),
  function(x) data.frame(
    XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(xmlChildren(x)),
    row.names = NULL
  )))
```

The entire file for this question is here:  https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/13&type=boardgame,boardgameexpansion,boardgameaccesory,rpgitem,rpgissue,videogame&versions=1&stats=1&videos=1&marketplace=1&comments=1

EDIT:  Here is my final solution.  It may not be elegant, but it works.

```
marketplace_df_func <- function(xmltop){

 marketplace_df <- data.frame(
listdate = xmlSApply(getNodeSet(xmltop, "//marketplacelistings//listing//listdate"), xmlValue),
currency = xmlSApply(getNodeSet(xmltop, "//marketplacelistings//listing//price[@currency]"), xmlAttrs),
price = xmlSApply(getNodeSet(xmltop, "//marketplacelistings//listing//price"), xmlValue),
condition = xmlSApply(getNodeSet(xmltop, "//marketplacelistings//listing//condition"), xmlValue))

marketplace_df$listdate <- substr(marketplace_df$listdate, 1, 25)

return(marketplace_df)}
```

Comment: There is no plural *listing**s*** in XML you post.

Comment: I added my final solution.  I could not get your answer to work for me.  Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1):

Since this XML now has more data in *elements* rather than *attributes*, simply run the accessible `xmlToDataFrame` without `lapply` looping:

```r
library(XML) 

url <- "..."
doc <- xmlParse(readLines(url))

listings_df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//listing"))
str(listings_df)
# 'data.frame': 103 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ listdate : chr  "Thu, 19 Jan 2006 22:08:15 +0000" "Mon, 29 Sep 2008 15:25:32 +0000" "Sat, 18 Jul 2009 20:42:03 +0000" "Fri, 04 Dec 2009 14:25:25 +0000" ...
#  $ price    : chr  "90.00" "34.95" "49.00" "40.00" ...
#  $ condition: chr  "likenew" "new" "verygood" "new" ...
#  $ notes    : chr  "Siedler von Catan / Settlers of Catan-Set (Basisspiel/basic game + Erweiterungen Die Seefahrer/ StÃ¤dte und Rit"| __truncated__ "Brand New Sealed Board Game. Released from MayFair Games.  Price is in USD.  If you wish to pay in CAD...then w"| __truncated__ "inlcudes 5/6 player expansion" "" ...
#  $ link     : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
```

To bind the underlying attributes use the special method:

```r
listings_df <- data.frame(
    xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//listing")),
    XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, "//listing/price")),
    XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, "//listing/link")),
    row.names = NULL
)
str(listings_df)
# 'data.frame': 103 obs. of  8 variables:
#  $ listdate : chr  "Thu, 19 Jan 2006 22:08:15 +0000" "Mon, 29 Sep 2008 15:25:32 +0000" "Sat, 18 Jul 2009 20:42:03 +0000" "Fri, 04 Dec 2009 14:25:25 +0000" ...
#  $ price    : chr  "90.00" "34.95" "49.00" "40.00" ...
#  $ condition: chr  "likenew" "new" "verygood" "new" ...
#  $ notes    : chr  "Siedler von Catan / Settlers of Catan-Set (Basisspiel/basic game + Erweiterungen Die Seefahrer/ StÃ¤dte und Rit"| __truncated__ "Brand New Sealed Board Game. Released from MayFair Games.  Price is in USD.  If you wish to pay in CAD...then w"| __truncated__ "inlcudes 5/6 player expansion" "" ...
#  $ link     : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
#  $ currency : chr  "EUR" "USD" "EUR" "EUR" ...
#  $ href     : chr  "https://boardgamegeek.com/market/product/40605" "https://boardgamegeek.com/market/product/116347" "https://boardgamegeek.com/market/product/158433" "https://boardgamegeek.com/market/product/181379" ...
#  $ title    : chr  "marketlisting" "marketlisting" "marketlisting" "marketlisting" ...
```

Comment: Odd! Solution worked great for me with posted URL. I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73848403/revisions) to show output of 103 obs data frame. Maybe your `xmltop` is not a parsed XML? Cheers!